# Is dofactory.com's Design Pattern Kit for C# worth the money?

Tags: design-patterns

It's not too pricey and I want to learn more about design patterns. Is this a decent product or is my money better spent somewhere else?

One advantage, potentially anyway, is it appears to be a good-sized chunk of content and usable offline, unlike Google or Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. i bought the first version and all updates after it. i never used it directly in my code, but it was always inspiring.

i can recommend C# Design Patterns by James W. Cooper (its old but very practical). i used many of his ideas in my windows forms projects. (e.g. chain of responibility for help system etc)

i would buy both again ;-)

Comment: btw. there is a free part on the dofactory page which is already very good.
http://dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx

Comment: http://www.amazon.de/Design-Patterns-Tutorial-Cooper-James/dp/0201844532/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&s=books-intl-de&qid=1282937216&sr=8-5

Comment: that is one of the worst books I have ever seen on C#. The guy is clearly Java taught and knows nothing about C#.

Answer (score 0):

Late to this thread but I have the set from them and it's very helpful, especially with refreshing yourself on what pattern X does and samples on how to use it.

They've recently released a javascript patterns set and I'll be getting that one too.